# Why the command executed is not that command found by "which"

Tags: macos, shell, svn

```
~$ which svn
/usr/local/bin/svn
~$ svn --version
-bash: /usr/bin/svn: No such file or directory
~$
```

$PATH:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/opt/google/chrome:~/nuts/shes

Comment: Is it possible that  `/usr/local/bin/svn` is a symlink?

Comment: `which` is not authoritative.  Show us the results of running `type svn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically happens after you've removed a command that used to be there. For efficiency reasons, `bash` doesn't scan the `PATH` every single time you run any command. Instead, it remembers the last location and avoids the lookup the next time.

You can make it forget all remembered locations with

```
hash -r
```

Afterwards, `svn --version` should find the new location.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables, also helpful